# Increment build version with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a Powershell script where I get the latest version of a `Pact` file and increment it to the next build version, which I will assign to a variable. I can get the current version with the below script:

```
$request = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://pactbroker:9292/pacts/provider/MyProvider/consumer/MyConsumer/latest"
$headers = $request.Headers
$headers["X-Pact-Consumer-Version"]
1.0.4
```

How do I then increment `$headers["X-Pact-Consumer-Version"]` to `1.0.5`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast the version string to [`System.Version`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version?view=net-5.0) which parses it into numeric properties `Major`, `Minor`, `Build` and `Revision`. Increment build number and format as string again.

```
$ver = [Version] $headers["X-Pact-Consumer-Version"]
$newVer = "{0}.{1}.{2}" -f $ver.Major, $ver.Minor, ($ver.Build + 1)
```